# Angular Testing - ERROR [karma]: { inspect: [Function: inspect] }

Tags: angular-cli, angular-test

I'm getting below error when trying to run our angular tests. Using Angular 5 on a Windows 10 machine. I've tried researching the error, but haven't made progress. Reaching out to see if anyone has encountered this before

```
yarn run test
yarn run v1.22.11
$ ng test --watch=false
 10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active11 10 2021 17:21:55.521:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
11 10 2021 17:21:55.524:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
11 10 2021 17:21:55.524:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
11 10 2021 17:21:55.527:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
11 10 2021 17:22:05.172:ERROR [karma]: { inspect: [Function: inspect] }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm kinda pissed off by Karma. It's way overcomplicated. It's not Unix philosophy for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: I was asked to look at an old Angular project and hit this today, too. It's Node version related. If I `nvm install 12.22.6 ; nvm use 12.22.6 ; npm test` it runs all the tests successfully. If I `nvm install 16.14.2 ; nvm use 16.14.2 ; npm test` then the tests crash with `ERROR [karma]: { inspect: [Function: inspect] }`. I'll have to do a binary search and figure out which specific version of Node breaks it.

Comment: Confirmed. Tests pass up to Node `15.0.1` (except for a webpack hiccup at `14.15.2`) but everything >= `15.1.0` throws the Karma error. This was a pretty old Angular 9 project, though, so I'm recommending to the product owner to upgrade it to something more modern.